# React Native Stack.Navigator does't work on Android

Tags: react-native, react-native-navigation

I have an issue with Stack.Navigator on Android. It just doesn't work by some strange reason.

There is simple code:

```
import React from 'react';
import {createNativeStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/native-stack';
import {ROUTES} from '../../constants/routes';
import {AuthScreen, LoginScreen, RegisterScreen} from './screens';

export const Unauthorized = () => {
  const Stack = createNativeStackNavigator();

  return (
    <Stack.Navigator
      initialRouteName={ROUTES.ROUTE_AUTH}
      screenOptions={{headerShown: false}}>
      <Stack.Screen name={ROUTES.ROUTE_AUTH} component={AuthScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={ROUTES.ROUTE_LOGIN} component={LoginScreen} />
      <Stack.Screen name={ROUTES.ROUTE_REGISTER} component={RegisterScreen} />
    </Stack.Navigator>
  );
};
```

Looks simple. AuthScreen component also is simple:

```
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StyleSheet, Text} from 'react-native';

export const AuthScreen = () => {
  return (
    <SafeAreaView>
      <Text style={styles.text}>Auth screen</Text>
    </SafeAreaView>
  );
};

const styles = StyleSheet.create({
  text: {
    color: 'red',
  },
});
```

There is a App.tsx:

```
import 'react-native-gesture-handler';
import React from 'react';
import {SafeAreaView, StatusBar, useColorScheme} from 'react-native';
import {Colors} from 'react-native/Libraries/NewAppScreen';
import {ApolloProvider} from '@apollo/client';
import client from './src/apollo';
import {SplashScreen} from './src/screens';

const App = () => {
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';

  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };

  return (
    <ApolloProvider client={client}>
      <SafeAreaView style={backgroundStyle}>
        <SplashScreen />
        <StatusBar backgroundColor="white" barStyle="dark-content" />
      </SafeAreaView>
    </ApolloProvider>
  );
};

export default App;
```

But screen is empty when app is Running.
But if I remove Stack.Navigator at all then the content gets visible

Any notes with dependencies or MainActivity I have done.

There is deps:

```
"@apollo/client": "^3.7.1",
"@react-navigation/native": "^6.0.6",
"@react-navigation/native-stack": "^6.2.5",
"@react-navigation/stack": "^6.0.11",
"graphql": "^16.6.0",
"react": "18.1.0",
"react-hook-form": "^7.39.1",
"react-native": "0.70.4",
"react-native-bootsplash": "^4.3.3",
"react-native-gesture-handler": "^2.8.0",
"react-native-mmkv-storage": "^0.8.0",
"react-native-safe-area-context": "^4.4.1",
"react-native-screens": "^3.10.0"
```

I spent 4 hours and I have no more ideas how to get Stask.Navigator to show content....

I tried to use

```
import {createStackNavigator} from '@react-navigation/stack'

const Stack = createStackNavigator()
```

instead of createNativeStackNavigator
I tried to change versions. Nothing helped.

Comment: May I ask that where do you use `Unauthorized` ? Inside App.js? If yes, please post the code about it.

Comment: Yes, I have added code of App.tsx. Thank you for ur comment.

Comment: I can see `<SplashScreen />` component is used, but I cannot find your `Unauthorized` component in App.tsx. And do your stack navigator have `<NavigationContainer>` wrapped? See information in [here](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/navigation-container/).

Comment: Thank you, Peter. The problem was with SafeAreaView styles. It had height: 0

Answer (score 0):

give flex:1 style to SafeAreaView in App.js

Comment: .... You are a genius, man. Yes, this was a problem. I'm stupid ))